# Display value on hover in AmChart - AmXYChart and enable zoom using mouse wheel

Tags: amcharts

For zoom, I tried using "mouseWheelZoomEnabled" property but as per the API it is only applicable for AmSerialChart.

Could not figure out how to display the value of a point on the graph when I hover on it.

Also I have multiple graphs where i mark the labels of the high points. How do i make the labels match the color of its graph? since i have multiple labels and they sometimes overlap and cause confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mouseWheelZoomEnabled` is not supported in XY chart. It may be added in the future, but there's no workaround for now.

---

To display hover balloon, you need bullets on your graph. If you don't want actual bullets showing up, you can "hide" them by setting [`bulletAlpha`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#bulletAlpha) to zero, but they need to be there. I.e.:

```
"graphs": [{
  // ...
  "bullet": "circle",
  "bulletAlpha": 0
}]
```

---

To set the color of the value label, use graph's [`color`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#color) property. You can set it to the same color as `lineColor` so that line and label color's match:

```
"graphs": [{
  // ...
  "lineColor": "#cc0000",
  "color": "#cc0000"
}]
```